# Hover option, or javascript

Tags: javascript, button, hover, structure

I'm making a practice website and I'm trying to add a hover effect to an image, the image being arrows to click back or forward. I assume something is wrong with the code, within its structure, or perhaps I would need to use javascript to achieve a rollover effect.

I made a fiddle to show the current work: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7VTy/1/

...I'm new to everything.

```
   <body>
   <div id="slider_wrapper">
    <div id="slider_container">
     <div class="controllers" id="previous"></div>

  <div id="slider">
  <img src="Images/slide_two.png" width="960" height="425" />
  <img src="Images/slide_one.png" width="960" height="425" />
  <img src="Images/slide_three.png" width="960" height="425" />
  </div>                           

  <div class="controllers" id="next"></div>
   </div>         
 </div>
 </body
```

Comment: You can use Jquery Cycle Plugin

Comment: check this It may help you http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: He's already using jQuery cycle, check his jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I understand your issue

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fdd2v/)

```
#previous:hover {
background-image: url(left_on.png);
}
```

would change the image

Comment: I see now why it wasn't working when I was trying to do this, I didn't have a different image, but rather I was trying to change the color. Awkward mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change slider_wrapper container from div to a tag and use hover state for the slider_wrapper. change display mode for #previous and #next to none, and add following style

```
#slider_wrapper:hover #previous, #slider_wrapper:hover #next{
    display:block;
}
```

see an example here http://jsfiddle.net/Z7VTy/3/

Comment: It was close to what I was trying to achieve. @mplungjan got what I was failing to do. Your advice helped for something else I was trying with a different assessment. Thanks!